# Host maven artifact with Cloudbees

Tags: java, maven, cloudbees

I managed to have my maven jar hosted in my private repo (at least this is what I see).

```
https://repository-{my-library}.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/
```

When I access it from the browser the folder 'org' shows up and browsing I can see the XML and jar.

The problem is when I try to use the jar for my app, I get this error:

```
Downloading: http://repository-{my-library}.forge.cloudbees.com/release/org/{my-library}/{my-library}/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://raw.github.com/{my-library}/spring-boot-legacy/mvn-repo/org/{my-library}/{my-library}/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.{my-library}:{my-library}:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to {my-library}-snapshot (http://repository-{my-library}.forge.cloudbees.com/release/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.{my-library}:{my-library}:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://repository-{my-library}.forge.cloudbees.com/release/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of {my-library}-snapshot has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.{my-library}:{my-library}:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to {my-library}-snapshot (http://repository-{my-library}.forge.cloudbees.com/release/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
```

I don't understand why I can accesss the repo snapshot from the browser yet maven says "Unauthorized"?

Comment: How about using command like `curl` to test? The browser may have the authenticated cookie of the site so that you can see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a custom *settings.xml* to your private repository, mount it and load the configuration from there. Otherwise you won't be able to access your (protected) artifacts.

The documentation is pretty well hidden, but you can find it here: http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Accessing+under+an+external+Maven+repository

Comment: How about making the artifact public? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, at https://console.cloudbees.com/a/<your-account>/repos/#/item=release under *Configure* you can make the whole folder public (release, snapshot, backup)

Comment: I can only see "Public: Accessible to all users"

Comment: Yes — that makes your artifacts public. If you know the URL, you can download them; no authentication required

Comment: Actually Jenkins still get "Unauthorized" even with this setting

Comment: Even when you set release / snapshot (whichever you need) to public? In that case you'll need to raise a ticket with Cloudbees, that's IMHO not the intended behaviour